# SharePoint Calendar Reminders

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-email

I know there is lots out there on doing this but I can't seem to get them working so i'm hoping someone could post step-by-step instructions on how to do this.

I'm looking to create an alert system within SharePoint so when a Change is added into the calendar for (e.g. 06/06/2016) the day before (e.g. 05/06/2016) there will be an e-mail alert sent out to X@123.com, Z@123.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say you can't seem to get them working, you need to tell us what you've tried and what about it didn't work. We'll try to get you the rest of the way.

Comment: @ErinL - Sorry about that - i've gone through this guide: https://kmlsp.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/how-to-add-reminder-to-a-calendar/

and it doesn't send the reminder e-mails - I currently have the following in sharepoint designer and published to my site:

    Stage:Stage 1
 If Current Item:Add Reminder equals Yes
  If Current Item:Remind Date not equals Variable: Today
   Pause until Current Item:Remind Date
   Email Alex
Transition to stage
 Go to End of Workflow


This manages to send the first e-mail but not reminders

Comment: Ok, that method is straight up insane overkill. I'll post a better solution.

Comment: Are you in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new workflow in SharePoint Designer that runs when a new item is created. Use the `Add Time to Date` action to subtract 1 day from the meeting day to get your reminder date. Then use `Pause until Date` using your reminder date. After the pause, use `Send Email` action.

Comment: Thanks, i've just got this together in designer....not sure if it's right? It seems to make sense to me - What do you think?



    Stage:emailReminder
 Add 0 months, -1 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes to Current Item:Start      Time (Output to Variable: reminderDate )
 Pause until Variable: reminderDate
 Email Alex 
    Transition to stage
 Go to End of Workflow

Comment: Looks right to me. Why don't you test it with a calendar event for tomorrow? It should send you an email since it's waiting until "Today."

Comment: It seems to work, i've just slapped an event in for Saturday at 8AM so lets see what happens overnight :) Thanks - I'll let you know how it goes! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked perfectly! Also thanks for telling me where to go as opposed to giving the logic! I'm new to all this so it helps me a lot!